# Fetching data using React to a Python backend

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am using python (bottle framework) as backend and React as frontend. I want to fetch data from React through *"http://127.0.0.1:8080/"* using **useEffect** Hook. The problem is I keep getting:

[image]

**Here is my backend (python)**

```
@get('/')
def _():
    data = {
        'name': 'Alvin',
        'lastname': 'Johnson'
    }
    return json.dumps(data)
```

**And here is the frontend (react)**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [data, setdata] = useState({
    name: '',
    lastname: ''
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/').then((res) =>
      res.json()).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setdata({
          name: data.name,
          lastname: data.lastname
        });
      })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to Python-React app</h1>
      <p>{data.name}</p>
      <p>{data.lastname}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**I have also added "proxy" on package.json file**

```
"proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to put in the entire api url in the fetch. fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/')

Comment: How far into the fetch logic does your code get? Fails on `fetch`? Fails on `res.json()`? Somewhere else? The error is simply informing you that your code isn't catching and handling thrown errors and rejected promises. What debugging has been done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using axios, thats what I use for my Flask backend.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [data, setdata] = useState({
    name: '',
    lastname: ''
  });

  const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/`)
      setdata(response.data);
      }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(); 
      }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to Python-React app</h1>
      <p>{data.name}</p>
      <p>{data.lastname}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```